# Trying to delete an application that always says it is open (in this case AVG AntiVirus.app)

Tags: terminal, applications, macos

This is the troubleshooting I've done so far:

1. Went to **Applications>Utilities>Activity Monitor** and force quit the process. Shortly after doing that AVG shows up again in activity monitor.
2. I went to terminal and typed in `rm -rf` hit return and then dragged the application to terminal. Once it showed me the path of the file I hit delete. Then terminal came back and said (-bash: /Applications/AVG AntiVirus.app: is a directory)

How the heck do I delete AVG AntiVirus on my computer?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to properly uninstall AVG AntiVirus for Mac first.

See: [How to uninstall AVG AntiVirus for Mac](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en_US&urlName=How-to-uninstall-AVG-AntiVirus-for-Mac)

> To uninstall AVG Antivirus for Mac:
>
> 1. Run the AVG AntiVirus for Mac
> 2. Click the **AVG AntiVirus** Menu bar, and click **Uninstall AVG AntiVirus**
> 3. Click **Continue** to begin the uninstallation process
> 4. AVG will run the uninstallation
> 5. The Uninstallation is now complete, please click **Restart** to reboot your computer

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. I never uninstalled an application through the menu bar within the application before.